# Prove that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Prove that the function below is **not differentiable** at $x=0$:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
x & \mbox{if $x$ is rational}\\
0 & ~~\mbox{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

---

I can prove a similar question which is to prove the function below is differentiable at $x=0$ by using squeeze theorem, but can't solve the question above.
\begin{align*}
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
x^2 & \mbox{if $x$ is rational}\\
0 & ~~\mbox{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

Comment: try with the definition?

Comment: Hint : Observe the limit of the difference quotient i.e $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I write an answer, but I'm not sure is it legit to seperate it into 2 cases assuming $\Delta x$ is rational or irrational, instead of calculating the righthand limit and lefthand limit of f'(x) (which I don't actually know how to calculate).

Comment: My personal view, since $f'(x)$ is oscillating between 0 and 1, as $\Delta x$ changes between rational and irrational, so $f'(x)$ doesn't approach a particular value, so it isn't exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$

$0$ is rational, so $f(0)=0$

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Consider two sequences, $a_n=\frac{1}n, b_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n},~~ n=1,2,3...$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(a_n)}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1/n}=1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{0}{\sqrt{2}/n}=0$$

The limit doesn't exist, so the function is not differentiable at $0$

Comment: This looks like a question from elementary calculus, where one probably have not proved that $\pi$ is irrational. You could take $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ to make your proof elementary.

Comment: Thank you, edit it already. @jjagmath

Comment: Thank you for answering, your answer seems very intuitive for me.

Comment: Great, glad it helps and you are welcome :) @BrokenDreams

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of differentiable, we have to check $f'(0)$ exists or not.

$$f'(0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(0+\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$

Case 1: $\Delta x$ is rational

$$f'(0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x}=1$$

Case 2: $\Delta x$ is irrational

$$f'(0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{0}{\Delta x}=0$$

obviously two limits are not equal, so $f'(0)$ isn't exists, so $f(0)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$